# flask-cache resulting in a name error when in a blueprint/app factory

Tags: python, caching, flask

currently, I have an application factory which looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.cache import Cache
from config import config

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
cache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

def create_app(environment):
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object(config[environment])

  bootstrap.init_app(app)
  cache.init_app(app)

  from main import main as base_blueprint
  from charts.statistics import statistics
  app.register_blueprint(base_blueprint)
  app.register_blueprint(statistics, url_prefix='/statistics')

  return app
```

following this pattern, I have my statistics blueprint. The `__init__.py` within the `charts/` directory is simply as follows:

```
from flask import Blueprint
statistics = Blueprint('statistics', __name__)
from . import statistics_charts
```

... and `statistics_charts.py` simply has the following

```
@statistics.route('/summary_chart')
@cache.memoize(timeout=5000)
def summary_chart():
  # ...
  return jsonify(my_data)
```

However, when I try to run this, it constantly gives me a name error, saying that cache was never defined. This worked in other apps, which were simply one file, but does not seem to work with the application factory and blueprints style.

What must be done for the cache to work in blueprints?

Comment: charts.statistics is a blueprint in the package charts.  Do you have a module named charts.statistics?  It appears that you do because of this import: from charts.statistics import statistics  If not, I'm not sure how that import is even working.

Comment: I fixed that right after I submitted this question, actually. It actually didn't do anything, which was kind of frustrating. Not entirely sure how it was working originally

Answer (score 1):

move the two `cache` lines to the `statistics_charts.py` file.  It'll then complain about `statistics` not being defined, but that's an easy fix.

Comment: I believe I found the problem: the `init_app` was supposed to receive the configuration, not the class instantiation

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following import statement to the top of your blueprint.

```
from . import cache
```